# how to call web service deployed in a VPS

Tags: web-services, tomcat, vps

I have deployed a restful web service in a godaddy vps.
this VPS can be connected via ipaddress:port(port provided to me).
i.e. 108.XX.XX.XX:43XX
Now, i have installed tomcat 7 in VPS, and i have deployed a RESTful web service in tomcat on port 8080.
i can call the web service from inside the VPS as ipaddress:8080/webServiceName but not able to call it from any other system(other than my VPS).

How can i fix this issue ??

I have checked many places for fixing this issue, but the only thing i find is how to deploy web service in tomcat.

Please Help..!!

Comment: Are you able to ping the server IP from your local system?

Comment: BTW, what sense does it make to have VPS allowed to be connected on a single port. You should have access to all the ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with Firewall on your server. Try allowing the required port and it should be able to connect.